# Did John von Neumann make any comments about the Many Worlds Interpretation of Hugh Everett?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, von-neumann

I was having a discussion with a physicist about Many Worlds Interpretation and he told me that von Neumann like the idea of having multiple worlds in quantum mechanics. When I asked him about more details, he recalled a story he heard about Richard Feynman rushing to von Neumann's office at Princeton referring to a book that von Neumann published where at some point talked about a non-unitary evolution of quantum mechanics. Feynman asked him "*what is this nonsense*" and von Neumann replied "*the postulate is just there until we finally understand what is happening in the measurement process*". The physicist then told me that if the story is true then von Neumann must have realized that non-unitary time evolution cannot occur, and if that cannot happen, then Many Worlds must be true.

Even if von Neumann said that, is it necessarily true that he would have supported the Many Worlds Interpretation?

Comment: Von Neumann died in Feb 1957, before Everett's thesis submission, and was too sick from cancer to have been involved with the 1956 draft of said thesis, which was circulated to several physicists acknowledged in the thesis, but not JvN. The thesis attacks several points associated with JvN's name. So a conjectural fantasy about his intellectual support for the MWI position is resoundingly unwarranted.

Comment: @CosmasZachos OP is suggesting this happened independently,  before Everett.

Comment: But... Everett all but attacked JvN!! At the time, he, JvN,  represented the orthodoxy. He thanked Groenewold, likely because he, H.G., caught JvN's plain error  vis-a-vis phase space quantization....